# JSON : Create 1 array from 2 json strings

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have written some PHP code which generates 2 JSON responses. I need to create a another one (in PHP or JavaScript)

The first one is:

```
{ "date": [ 1428912000, 1428915600, 1428919200, 1428922800 ] }
```

The second one is:

```
{ "values": [ 4.932, 4.934, 4.935, 4.937 ] }
```

The result in need is this:

```
{ 
    "new": [
        [ 1428912000, 4.932 ],
        [ 1428915600, 4.934 ],
        [ 1428919200, 4.935 ],
        [ 1428922800, 4.937 ]
    ]
}
```

How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assumption taken is that both the arrays are of the same size

```
var date = {"date":[1428912000,1428915600,1428919200,1428922800]}
var values = {"values":[4.932,4.934,4.935,4.937]}
var obj = {new: []}
for(var i=0;i<date.date.length;i++){
    obj["new"].push([date.date[i],values.values[i]])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the two response arrays, combine the corresponding elements into an array, and push this onto the result array.

```
var result = { new: [] };
for (var i = 0; i < response1.date; i++) {
    result.new.push([response1.date[i], response2.values[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all parse your JSON-Arrays to javascript arrays:

```
var dates = JSON.parse({"date":[1428912000,1428915600,1428919200,1428922800]});
var values = JSON.parse({"values":[4.932,4.934,4.935,4.937]})
```

now that you have two javascript-arrays, you can combine them as you like, preferrably using a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use php array function.
[array_combine($keys, $values)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php).